# Storing the map contents into another map in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the below java class

```
public class DataStruc {

    private List<String> TradeRef;
    private List<String> TMS;

     public DataStruc(List<String> TradeRef, List<String> TMS) {
        setTradeRef(TradeRef);
        setTMS(TMS);
    }

    //setters and getters for them

    }
```

I have the below map which is as shown below and into which i am explicitly creating the list

```
Map<String, DataStruc> newdatamap = new HashMap<String, DataStruc>();
List<String> B1TradeRef = Arrays.asList("TradRefr", "tr1");
List<String> B1TMS = Arrays.asList("TS", "TMSW");

List<String> B2TradeRef = Arrays.asList("TradRefrtsy", "tr1ty");
List<String> B2TMS = Arrays.asList("TWES", "TUYTMSW");

newdatamap.put("B1", new DataStruc (B1TradeRef,B1TMS));
newdatamap.put("B2", new DataStruc (B2TradeRef,B2TMS));
```

below is the output of the above program as  shown below

```
output :-
*******

B1 = com.asd.ert.DataStruc@1394894
B2 = com.asd.ert.DataStruc@1394894
```

Now I want to retrieve the value of above `HashMap` named `newdatamap`  as I want to store it like this format in another map named `finalmap`.Please advise how to achieve this?

lets say my `finalmap` declartion is like

```
Map<String , String> finalmap = new HashMap<String , String>();
```

so if `newdatamap.keyset` is equal to  B1 then following should be stored in `finalmap`.Please advise how to achieve this

```
TradRefr                TradeRef
tr1                     TradeRef //class member name declartions
TS                       TMS 
TMSW                     TMS     //class member name declartions
```

Comment: Can you explain more on what data you want to get from `newdatamap` to store it in `finalmap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TMSW                     TMS     //**class member name declartions**

So you want to extract field names here of class `DataStruc`. There is only one way to do that in java, which is using reflection API.

Your `DataStruc` class

```
import java.util.List;

    public class DataStruc {

        private List<String> TradeRef;
        private List<String> TMS;

        public DataStruc(List<String> TradeRef, List<String> TMS) {
            this.TradeRef = TradeRef;
            this.TMS = TMS;
        } // setters and getters for them

    }
```

Calling class.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalAccessException {

        Map<String, DataStruc> newdatamap = new HashMap<String, DataStruc>();
        List<String> B1TradeRef = Arrays.asList("TradRefr", "tr1");
        List<String> B1TMS = Arrays.asList("TS", "TMSW");

        List<String> B2TradeRef = Arrays.asList("TradRefrtsy", "tr1ty");
        List<String> B2TMS = Arrays.asList("TWES", "TUYTMSW");

        newdatamap.put("B1", new DataStruc(B1TradeRef, B1TMS));
        newdatamap.put("B2", new DataStruc(B2TradeRef, B2TMS));

        Map<String, String> finalmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // loop through current map
        for (Map.Entry<String, DataStruc> entry : newdatamap.entrySet()) {

            String key = entry.getKey();
            DataStruc dataStruc = entry.getValue();

            // get all the fields of object dataStruc
            for (Field field : dataStruc.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                String fieldName = field.getName();
                // check if field is List<String>
                if (field.get(dataStruc) instanceof List) {
                    List<String> fieldValue = (List<String>) field.get(dataStruc);
                    // if yes then add the List entries to your final map with
                    // current field name
                    for (String str : fieldValue) {
                        finalmap.put(str, fieldName);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : finalmap.entrySet())
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "-" + entry.getValue());

    }

}
```

Output after running Main class

```
TUYTMSW-TMS
tr1-TradeRef
TradRefrtsy-TradeRef
TWES-TMS
TradRefr-TradeRef
TMSW-TMS
tr1ty-TradeRef
TS-TMS
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise but still i am getting the complier error on this line  if(field.get(dataStruc) instanceof List<String>){ , please advise how to overcome from this complie error as the error that i am getting is can not perform instance of check against parametrized type List<String>

Comment: @fdsffgfhgfgh Try using just `List` instead of `List<String>`

Comment: done that and compilation error was removed but when i iterate over map i did not get the results which i was trring to achieve

Comment: @fdsffgfhgfgh - what output you got in the finalmap ?

Comment: Iterator it = finalmap.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                System.out.println("*************");
                System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());

Comment: after this i try to iterate the final map but i did not get anything in console

Comment: size of map is also 0

Comment: @fdsffgfhgfgh : There was one small correction in code. You have to use `dataStruc.getClass().getDeclaredFields()` instead of `dataStruc.getClass().getFields()` . Updated in answer

Comment: but in my pojo the class memebers is being declared as private so the runtime exception that i get is can not access private members java .lang.illegalacessexception

Comment: @fdsffgfhgfgh : updated again. use `field.setAccessible(true);`

Comment: @fdsffgfhgfgh : posted whole code which I ran and got the output. You can check the code and see if you are doing wrong somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the advise but now i am getting complie time error on this line  finalmap.add(str,fieldName); suggestion add cast to final map please advise how to overcome from this

Comment: @fdsffgfhgfgh . There is no add for map. Use put. And it was a typo in old post . I have updated it. Please refer latest code which I have posted in answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Map<String , String> finalmap = newdatamap.values().stream()
        .flatMap(d -> Stream.concat(
            d.getTradeRef().stream().map(s -> new SimpleEntry<>(s, "TradeRef")),
            d.getTMS().stream().map(s -> new SimpleEntry<>(s, "TMS"))))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
    System.out.println(finalmap);
    // -> {TUYTMSW=TMS, tr1=TradeRef, TradRefrtsy=TradeRef, TWES=TMS, TradRefr=TradeRef, TMSW=TMS, TS=TMS, tr1ty=TradeRef}
```

class SimpleEntry is an public inner class of java.util.AbstractMap.

Comment: Thanks for the advise but i am still using jdk 1.5 in my project please advise how can i solve this in jdk 1.5